# Error PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting end of file in

Tags: php, html

Estoy trabajando en php, soy novato en esto y me aparece el siguiente error

> "PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting end of file in"

a que se debe esto y como lo puedo solucionar?

```
 <?php
        include ("conexion.php");
        $query="SELECT * FROM encargado";
        $resultado= $conexion -> query($query);
        while($row=$resultado -> fetch_assoc()) {
          ?>           
       <?php
```

Comment: @Sr1871 Eso no es cierto, si que puedes dejar espacios delante o detras de `->`. Revisa que no te falte algun punto y coma o que estes utilizando `->` en un lugar que no corresponde. En el código que muestras no aparenta haber ningun error de sintaxis.

Comment: Tienes razón, no sé porque tenía la idea, gracias por la correción, borró comentario para evitar confusiones, específica la linea donde te marca el error

Comment: cierra el ciclo `while` con un  `}` para después agregar tu codigo dentro, finaliza con el `?>` si abres otro php abajo muestra tu codigo o elimina el ultimo `<?php`

Comment: El error puede ser porque no tienes nada dentro del `while` o porque tienes una versión de PHP inferior a la `5.4`.

Comment: EL error me da justo en estas lineas                                             
      $resultado= $conexion -> query($query);
        while($row=$resultado -> fetch_assoc())                                                      y el while esta cerrado solo copie una parte del codigo

Comment: @ErickMuñoz ¿puedes incluir tambien el codigo de `conexion.php`?, además el include no necesita los paréntesis, puedes colocar solo `include 'conexion.php';`

Answer (score 1):

intenta solo cerrarlo con `?>` al final, es decir, así:

```
<?php
        include ("conexion.php");
        $query="SELECT * FROM encargado";
        $resultado= $conexion -> query($query);
        while($row=$resultado -> fetch_assoc()) {

?>
```

NOTA: recuerda que `{` es para abrir un bloque de código y luego cierras con `}`

Comment: En el estándar psr-12 se indica que para archivos de solo PHP debe omitirse el cierre ?> https://php-fig.org/psr/psr-12